# How do I install Android Storage Access Framework?

Tags: adb

I have uninstalled the Android Storage Access Framework app via ADB and now I can't access the data and obb folders on my phone.

I would like to know how I could reinstall this app.

I tried to find the apk to reinstall the app, but ended up finding nothing.

Comment: That should be a system app which means it shouldn't be possible to uninstall it., if you have uninstalled it I assume your device is rooted? If yes the reinstall the ROM you use. And next time think twice before using root permissions to delete something.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but no, my device is not rooted.

Comment: Then you can not uninstall an app like Android Storage Framework, you can only disable it. So you simply have to re-enable it. Try https://android.stackexchange.com/q/215313/2241

Comment: Hello again. Thank you for the answer. I tested several solutions, including several codes by ladb, but I could not solve my problem. When I execute a command, the following message appears: "Inaccessible or not found".

Answer (score 0):

For those who uninstall system  Android Storage access framework apo via ADB or LADB. Leaving you unable to open Android data or obb well there is solution for you. It's simple and easy method:-
Download Ex File Manager from Google Play store

1. Enter the apo
2. Go to system
3. Select Priv-app folder
4. Select DocumentsUIGoogle
5. From there you can see the app install from there